# Adobe Flex key capturing

Tags: flex3, keypress

In my Flex application when click <kbd>F11</kbd> key the page gets into full screen and disturbs the shape of the page. Can anyone help me out in capturing the <kbd>F11</kbd> key. I am using  IE7.

Comment: F11 is the default short cut key for changing browser into fullscreen mode (in IE and FF at least). I don't think we can override it.

Comment: I see what u mean: FF doesn't go full screen if SWF is in focus, but IE does. Waiting for a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be capturing the <kbd>F11</kbd> key - you should either be capturing the resize event of your application and resizing your components manually, or using the Flex layout containers so that you don't have to code all of that.